# Get a group of sums without excluding instances where some groups have no entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

Right now, I'm trying to group a set of sums from a database into a 2D array. As it stands, the code looks something like this:

```
@TwoDArray = Array.new
@eachPossibleValue.each do |specificValue|
        @innerArray= Array.new
        @innerEachPossibleValue.each do |innerSpecificValue|
            @innerArray.push(@database.where(fieldOne: specificValue).where(fieldTwo: innerSpecificValue).sum("y_value"))
        end
        @twoDArray.push(@innerArray)
end
```

As you can see, it's a mess of O(n*m) queries each time this runs, but it works. It makes an inner array of the specific combinations, and then pushes that array to the main array, rinse and repeat for all the possible outer values. We were able to come up with a close answer to getting this all done in just one query:

```
@database.group(:fieldOne, :fieldTwo).order("fieldOne", "fieldTwo")
    .pluck("sum(y_value)").each_slice(numberOfUniqueFieldTwoEntries).to_a
```

This would have worked for what we wanted... I think. It just gets a large array of all the values like an unfolded 2D array, but then slices it since it's uniform (as times when there aren't any entries would just result in 0 in its place.)

Problem is, since some combinations of fieldOne, fieldTwo have no entries, they're skipped. The naive approach of each_slice no longer works, since there aren't any zeroes there; they're just excluded.

Is there a way to get those sums in a single query, while also including instances where certain combinations yield no entries?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `where.not(:fieldOne => nil)` to your activerecord query

```
@database.group(:fieldOne, :fieldTwo).order("fieldOne", "fieldTwo").
where.not(:fieldOne => nil).where.not(:fieldTwo => nil).
.pluck("sum(y_value)").each_slice(numberOfUniqueFieldTwoEntries).to_a
```